# Is it possible to transform DOCTYPE using SlowCheetah?

Tags: xml, slowcheetah

I am applying transforms to a custom XML config file using SlowCheetah, but ran into a snag. How would I go about transforming this:

```
<!DOCTYPE ParameterSet [ <!ENTITY someValue "10"> ]>
```

into this:

```
<!DOCTYPE ParameterSet [ <!ENTITY someValue "20"> ]>
```